# Can I automate an audio playlist to play at certain times, in a desired order?

Tags: windows, audio, automation, windows-task-scheduler

I currently use Windows Task Scheduler to play certain playlists at certain times of the day/week, which we broadcast online as part of scheduled programming. Each time the task executes, it opens the playlist in Windows Media Player and begins playing a random audio file in it, which is fine for those purposes.

Now, however, I have a need for non-randomized scheduling. In other words, we have a list of about 90 audio files that need to be played in order, each one twice a day, then moving on to the next one, and continually/endlessly repeating that cycle. So the schedule would go audio 1 (morning), audio 1 (evening), next day audio 2 (morning), audio 2 (evening), next day... and eventually audio 90 (morning), audio 90 (evening), then back to audio 1 (morning), etc.

I have absolutely no idea how to do something like this using Task Scheduler or any other program. Is it possible to set something like this up, perhaps using another program I have not heard of? (If someone knows how to do this, we might even be willing to pay you a small fee to do so.)

Hope you guys can help, thanks very much!

Isaac

Comment: Take a look at bms http://www.nch.com.au/bms/ I think it has everything you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I looked into it but I didn't see the ability to do what I need, at least not without knowing how to write scripts (which I don't). If you know how to set what we need up using this or any other program, and would be willing to do so for a fee, contact me and we can talk about it. Thanks.